# nginx: [emerge] unknown "1" variable - when using curly braces around variables numbers

Tags: php, regex, nginx, url-rewriting

In this rule

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?param1=${1}&param2=${2}&param3=${3}&param4=${4}&param5=${5}&param6=${6}&param7=${7}&param8=${8}&param9=${9}&param10=${10} last;
}
```

i tried to pass the limit of 9 parameters so i used curly braces around the variables numbers but gave me this error message

```
nginx: [emerge] unknown "1" variable
```

Comment: Maybe it doesn't have a definition for ${`1`}. Is that otherwise assigned elsewhere, like `$1 = "hey"` ? Seperatly, there seems to be a literal space in the regex `(.+)<space>/index`

Comment: @sln i do not know a lot about how nginx works with rewriting but it works as intended if i used `$1` instead of `${1}` even if i ended the regex with `$` but will add it now to prevent confusion.

Comment: Any expression that contains braces must be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @RichardSmith as in `${"1"}`?

Comment: @RichardSmith fixed the typo and used quotes but gave me same error as above i think numeric parameters has a limit of 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use certain characters (`}` or `;`) in some expressions, you need to enclose the entire expression within single or double quotes.

However, this question relates to the fact that only the first 9 captures are available as numeric captures in Nginx.

But you can use named captures (even if only for the 10th capture).

For example:

```
rewrite ^/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(?<a>.+)$
/index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4&param5=$5&param6=$6&param7=$7&param8=$8&param9=$9&param10=$a
last;
```

The named capture `(?<a>.+)` places the capture into a variable `$a`.